# Dict comprehension, avoid data from being overwritten

Tags: python, dictionary

On the input side I have a list of lists, i.e. as follows

```
[
  ['name1', 1,2,3,4],  # name, val1, val2, val3, val4
  ['name2', 4,3,6,2],
  ['name3', 9,6,4,9],
  ['name1', 10,3,12,4],
  ['name2', 1,4,3,2]
]
```

which is then converted to namedtuple (names above). To convert it to dict, I tried

```
result = {data.name: data for data in data_list}
```

but that overwrites the entry when the same name appears again. What I would like to achieve is, that the key/value is always

```
{'name': [[]]}
```

even if there is only one list per name. If there are multiple accourences of the same name, additional lists should be added instead of overwriting existing lists.

Can this be done in a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: This problem is seemingly so common that I'd like to see a standard library implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Can this be done in a dictionary comprehension? **NO**, unless you want to take an extra mile of sorting and grouping the data. That will steal readability from the code and its not worth the effort

**Implementation**

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby    
{ k : zip(*zip(*v)[1:])
      for k, v in groupby(sorted(data, key = itemgetter(0)), key = itemgetter(0))}
```

**Output**

```
{'name1': [(1, 2, 3, 4), (10, 3, 12, 4)],
 'name2': [(4, 3, 6, 2), (1, 4, 3, 2)],
 'name3': [(9, 6, 4, 9)]}
```

For cases like this you need to use `defaultdict`

**Implementation**

```
data = [
  ['name1', 1,2,3,4],  # name, val1, val2, val3, val4
  ['name2', 4,3,6,2],
  ['name3', 9,6,4,9],
  ['name1', 10,3,12,4],
  ['name2', 1,4,3,2]
]
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for elem in data:
    data_dict[elem[0]].append(elem[1:])
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, 
{'name1': [(1, 2, 3, 4), (10, 3, 12, 4)],
 'name2': [(4, 3, 6, 2), (1, 4, 3, 2)],
 'name3': [(9, 6, 4, 9)]})
```

Comment: I've removed -1 although you should've focused on why it can't be done by dict comprehension.

Comment: @freakish: I personally don;t think its a good approach to leave a downvote without a comment, as that does not add any value. If you think the answer can be improved leave a comment so that the respondent can come back and modify it :-)

Comment: I wanted to comment but you've edited your answer in the meantime. Plus I was commenting the other answer as well. So it's just a coincidence, not my bad will.

Comment: @freakish: Also I think the general approach I have seen by lot of respondents in an evolving answer. So, if you see the answer now, it both answers the question as well as provides an advise on the best practice

Comment: @Abhijit: The "non dict comprehension" way is what I'm using actually. I was interested whether it can be done in a comprehension too.

Comment: @all: Was the question so stupid to downvote it twice? Just wonder.

Comment: @mstuebner: +1 from my side. It seems that people could not find a reasoning as to why you would insist on a dict comprehension where `defaultdict` is the obvious choice.